# XAMPP 1.8.2 (with PHP 5.4) token mismatch and Configurable menus: Disabled

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP 1.8.2 (with PHP 5.4) for Windows XP.

When run `localhost/phpmyadmin` and click something in phpMyAdmin page it shows "token mismatch" as below:

[image]

I have followed the related posts on Stack Overflow but I still didn't get it.

Comment: must be some config problem have you tried to click on the link in 1st warning?

Comment: @scx: where is thar 1st warning.I just confused. can you help?

Comment: on the bottom of the page "The phpmyadmin configuration storage... "

Comment: @scx: please see this link http://imgur.com/6inhbqh

Comment: Is there anything special about your configuration? A load balancing server or proxy or some such? The "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" error isn't what's causing the token mismatch or login problems. Check your `session.save_path` directory -- make sure it's defined in php.ini and make sure it's got proper permissions.